# Python pandas json - excel file and json output character length isn't the same. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, json, pandas, python-requests

I need help to understand what is going on, I'm new to programming, I always do my research if I get stuck. However this topic got me stuck for a few days.

I'm doing a project, where I scrape data from a website. My problem is, the excel file I generate from the python script is missing some data.

**For example:
The output excel file in a line has: 30438 characters
In Thonny /print(data)/ the same line has: 35310 characters
**

Here's my code, I use Thonny:

```
#API
import requests
import json
import time

#IMPORTING URLs FROM TXT
import numpy as np

#NICE DATA
import pandas as pd
import csv

#WHERE ARE THE WEBSITE IDs
datafromfile=np.loadtxt("url_ids.txt",dtype="str")

#EVENTS URL LIST 
UrlList = datafromfile

res = []

for myUrl in UrlList:
    url = f"https://myrandomwebsite.com/api/v3/event/{myUrl}/teams"

    payload = ""
    headers = {
    [...]
    }
    
    r = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

    data = r.json()
    output = json.dumps(data)
    
    print(data)
    
    res.append(data)
    time.sleep(0.5)  # sleep for at least half a second

df = pd.json_normalize(res)

#OVERRIDE HTML NEW LINE 
df = df.replace(r'\r\n','|',regex=True)

df.to_excel('MyGreatExcelFile.xlsx',sheet_name='MyGreatExcelFile',header=True)
```

I hope someone can chime in, and tell me, how can I improve my code.

Thank you!

My dummy brain thought that "time.sleep(0.5)" will help me. However this wasn't the problem.

Comment: How do you calculate your characters per line? Can you give a few cells of your data? It might be that you do not "loose" any data, but that it is just a syntax difference between the excel and "print" format. Can you check if you still have the same number of columns?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. Well, i definitely don't have the same number of columns. So it is not a problem that I have less white spaces and so on.
For example, my row should look like this in the end of the row:" .... {'id'  '123456'  'ssoId'  '67890'  'firstName'  'Joe'  'lastName' Doe'  'gender' 18  'nationality'  'BEL'  'dateOfBirth'  None  'homeCity'  'Constanța Constanţa'  'statusInTeam'  'Accepted'  'isCaptain'  False  'isExternal'  False}]}"
But in excel I see this:
" {'id'  '123456'  'ssoId'  '67890'  'firstName'  'Joe'  'lastName' Doe'    'age' 18  'nationality'".

Comment: As you can see, I'm missing some columns. However, before these columns, I have full data in excel file. Seems like something is happening during writing (data) to the excel file. Like the "df = pd.json_normalize(res)" can't handle too much character or something like this.

Comment: I uploaded a picture with an example: https://pasteboard.co/KoxRrw40IPeT.png /I marked the missing cells with yellow./
As you can see, sometimes I have a complete, finished row. Sometimes I do not have. a full row. 
However, if I copy from Thonny the print output, it has every data (cell).

Comment: Can you please share some URLs to get the working example?